# Wraparound widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking for way to implement **wraparound** widget in flutter. I need to create screen which space will be finite but unbounded, In other words I want to do something like when `widget1` leaves the side of the screen it have to reappear on the opposite side immediately. I have `stack` and thanks to `positioned` I am re-rendering new position of widget based on accelerometer.

I don't know where to even start looking, if there is some package for it or should I implement it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the package `carousel_slider`
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

It also features infinity scrolling which should provide the effect you want.